# How to associate the PNG/JPG Edit context menu with Paint.NET?

Tags: windows-xp, context-menu, file-association

Right now, when I right-click on a PNG or JPG, I get the Edit context menu which takes me to MSPaint.  How can I associate the Paint.NET with the Edit menu?

I've tried Tools/Folder Options/File Types, but I don't really see anything there.

[image]

Note that it says to click Advanced, but I don't see the Advanced button.  Also, the caption does not even refer to the right file type, so something is clearly corrupted.  I am seeing the same issue with the JPG entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools > Folder Options > File Types is the right place.

Find JPG/PNG in the list of extensions and then you'll see the Details for 'JPG/PNG' extension filled in below.

There's an "Open's with" label and icon + a button marked "Change...". This is for opening/viewing. Click on the "Advanced" button to get a dialog for the different options - edit, open and printto.

Select "edit" then the "Edit..." button. Browse to MSPaint. Don't forget to ensure that there's the "%1" (including quotes) after the exe to ensure that the file gets passed correctly.

Comment: I added more details - also I don't see the Advanced button.

Comment: That's strange.  Where you have a button that says Restore, it should say Advanced instead.

Comment: @AngryHacker - Where you have a button that says Restore, it should say Advanced (from @BBLake's comment). Interestingly the text refers to "P10" rather than "PNG". I think clicking "Restore" should be safe. You could try it and see if it changes to "Advanced".

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.  I clicked on Restore for the JPG and the button changed to Advanced.  I went into it and the Edit entry was missing, even though, it was still in the context menu.  I entered a new Edit entry, which fixed it.  Oddly enough, it also fixed the Edit association for the PNG as well, even though I did not mess with it at all.  The PNG File Types entry still has the Restore button.